# java.lang.ClassCastException on Sonar

Tags: java, junit, sonarqube

Recently I've been assigned to examine Java code coverage using Sonar with Maven. I run `mvn sonar:sonar` and the build comes out just fine, plus I can see the result from the dashboard.

However, the test cases come out as errors, which does not happen at all if I run it normally. Here is the error stack trace:

```
$Proxy11 cannot be cast to com.epsilon.agility.message.dao.MessageDAO
java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy11 cannot be cast to                    com.epsilon.agility.message.dao.MessageDAO
at  com.epsilon.agility.message.utils.MessageDBAdaptorService.getMessageDAO(MessageDBAdaptorSer vice.java:32)
at com.epsilon.agility.message.facade.MessageClassificationFacadeImpl.initilaizeDAOs(MessageClassificationFacadeImpl.java:91)
at com.epsilon.agility.message.facade.MessageClassificationFacadeImpl.<init>(MessageClassificationFacadeImpl.java:86)
at com.epsilon.agility.message.dao.test.TestMessageClassificationFacadeImpl.setUp(TestMessageClassificationFacadeImpl.java:85)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runBefores(ClassRoadie.java:49)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:36)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:62)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:140)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:127)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:177)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:345)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1009)
```

Here is the method involved in the error:

```
@BeforeClass
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, timeout = 10)
public static void setUp() throws IOException {
    conn = TestDBUtils.getDBConnection();

    MessageDBAdaptorService.init(conn);

    msgclassificationFacade = new MessageClassificationFacadeImpl(conn);

    messageDAO = MessageDBAdaptorService.getMessageDAO();
    messageAssetDAO = MessageDBAdaptorService.getMessageAssetDAO();
    channelDAO = MessageDBAdaptorService.getChannelDAO();
    folderItemDAO = MessageDBAdaptorService.getFolderItemDAO();
    folderDAO = MessageDBAdaptorService.getFolderDAO();


    Assert.assertNotNull(messageDAO);
    Assert.assertNotNull(messageAssetDAO);
    Assert.assertNotNull(channelDAO);
    Assert.assertNotNull(folderItemDAO);
    Assert.assertNotNull(folderDAO);

}
```

I've searched the solutions online but it seems that there is no similar solution for Sonar. I suspect that the problem *might* come from Sonar's different approach for test cases since the test cases run fine on normal basis.

I will post more code and information if the above are not enough. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be a Sonar problem.
From the stack trace I assume that maven surefire plugin can't execute a particular test.
If I were you I'd the following.
- Verify that you custom build and Sonar are using the same maven surefire plugin version and have the same configuration.

Comment: Yup, I checked the version and apparently I had to include some other dependencies. Now it's working, so thanks!